# 0x80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class - RemoteConnectionTool AxMSTSCLib

Tags: c#, com, mstsc, class-factory

I am currently trying to fix a problem, where my program doesnt work on some laptops.
Currently there are three laptops on which the program doesnt work. When starting the program on those following error message appears

```
ClassFactory kann angeforderte Klasse nicht liefern (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))

Geworfene Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
bei System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
bei RemoteConnectTool.Form1.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\username\Documents\GitRepos\Tools\RemoteConnectTool\RemoteConnectTool\Form1.Designer.cs:Zeile 94.
bei RemoteConnectTool.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\GitRepos\Tools\RemoteConnectTool\RemoteConnectTool\Form1.cs:Zeile 24.
bei RemoteConnectTool.Program.Main() in C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\GitRepos\Tools\RemoteConnectTool\RemoteConnectTool\Program.cs:Zeile 18.
```

On those laptops, it also doesnt work with my personal username, on which it worked on my laptop.
Some posts suggest reregister the class using regsvr32. But what what DLL do I need to add, in order to get the program running.

The weird thing is, when the program doesnt work, the error states my username instead of the logged in username.

It happens on Win10/Win11.

Program.cs Line 18:
`Application.Run(new Form1());`

Form1.cs Line 24
`ADUser = new List<User>();`

Start the program

- The error message appeared

Other laptops

- worked, there are only three laptops on which it didnt worked

Other users

- On the laptops on which it didnt worked, I tried differet users in order to rule out permission errors. It also didnt work, so it isnt a permission issue.

Rebuilding the project

- Hoping that the issue disappears, issue still persists

Comment: AxMSTSCLib corresponds to this ActiveX Control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/remote-desktop-activex-control-classes (in \windows\system32\mstscax.dll). This "Microsoft RDP Client Control" serves many versions of RdpClient (from 1 to 13). The 0x80040111 error means on the PC it runs the code is asking this ActiveX control a version that's not available. It's a setup deployment/issue (Windows vs Dev machine). You can also review your .cs or your form.designer.cs check for code like `new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient11()` and try a lower version like AxMsRdpClient9, etc.

Comment: This fixed the issue. I used the version 11, after switiching to version 9 it worked. I still have to test it on more laptops, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AxMSTSCLib` corresponds to this [Remote Desktop ActiveX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/remote-desktop-activex-control-classes), located in in `\windows\system32\mstscax.dll`.

This "Microsoft RDP Client Control" (that's its display name) serves many versions of the main class called `RdpClient`, currently from 1 to 13.

`0x80040111` error, aka `CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE` means the code is asking for a version of `RdpClient` that's not available on the PC it currently runs.

It's a setup deployment/issue, i.e. the program was developed on a PC that has a higher version than the program it runs. You can review your `.cs` files or your `form.designer.cs`, check for code like `new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient11()` and try a lower version like `AxMsRdpClient9`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was solved when I downgraded the version from 11 to 9.